# Refer to column headings csv Groovy

Tags: csv, groovy

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way of accessing column headings in a CSV using OpenCSV in groovy? This is what I have:

```
@GrabConfig( systemClassLoader=true )
@Grab( 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.27' )
@Grab(group = 'net.sf.opencsv', module = 'opencsv', version = '2.3')
import groovy.sql.Sql
import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader
import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVParser
def sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/nid", "developer","whatever", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
def notes = sql.dataSet("vdc_notifications")
def TEST_FILE_NAME = 'C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\test.csv'

List<String[]> rows = new CSVReader(new FileReader(new File(TEST_FILE_NAME)), CSVParser.DEFAULT_SEPARATOR, CSVParser.DEFAULT_ESCAPE_CHARACTER, CSVParser.DEFAULT_QUOTE_CHARACTER).readAll()
```

What i'm trying to get to is being able to do:

```
rows.each() { row -> println row.some_column_name }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

usually the first row of a CSV file contains the names of the columns.  so you can either use a simple parsing approach and take the first row for the header:

```
@Grab('net.sf.opencsv:opencsv:2.3')
import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader
import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.bean.CsvToBean;
import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.bean.HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy;

def csv = """\
name,age
Charlie,23
Billy,64"""

// read the files and keep the first one as the header
def csvr = new CSVReader(new StringReader(csv))
def header
while ((line=csvr.readNext())) {
    if (!header) {
        header = line
    } else {
        // create a map from the header and the line
        println([header,line].transpose().collectEntries())
    }
}
```

Or you can use the `CsvToBean` and the `HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy` to create beans:

```
class Person {
    String name
    Integer age
}

// use the mapper
def ctb = new CsvToBean<Person>()
def hcnms = new HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy<Person>()
hcnms.type = Person
println ctb.parse(hcnms, new StringReader(csv))
```

Comment: Hi cfrick, hrm I suppose the most efficient way is the second one really, I even spotted HeaderColumnNameMapping but didn't quite pick up on what it did!

Comment: So CsvToBean would cast the strings to the correct type, what about null values?

Comment: yes they are integers afterwards.  above examples are working.  so you can also try for yourself.  yet i'd assume, that the first example is better, where many rows are read, because it will read line by line.

Comment: Ahh yeah sorry your right so i'd do myRecords << [header,line].transpose().collectEntries(), lemmy go try it back in a sec, i've no doubt your right though.

Comment: Hmm need to do some reading around how to get this to read from a file, the code in my question doesn't translate to your answer it seems...

Comment: you use your filereader instead of the stringreader.  i just use that to illustrate a working example without the hastle of dealing with files.  otherwise please edit your question with what you have tried.

Comment: Yep thats got it, how silly do I feel! if I wanted to build up a map of everything i'd do def myRecords = [:] then myRecords << [header,line].transpose().collectEntries() ?

Comment: you can not build a map of everything.  each row would overwrite the previous row, as all have the same keys.

Comment: Tee hee yeah sorry just figured that out, i've been reading for abut 14 hours so losing the plot a bit now, time for a break I thinks